# How to check if multiple dialogs are open in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, dialog

I noticed that I can open multiple tabs from different buttons/links. :)

What i want to do is to be able to open a dialog box only if no other dialog box is opened.

I can use an if statement and check for each id that has a dialog attached to it, but there are a lot of them in my page.

I need some king of expression that `if (a dialog id open) {do not open $(this) dialog}` or `open $(this)dialog only if no other dialog is open`.

Comment: what dialog are you using? jquery ui?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`isOpen`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#option-disabled) method on the dialog to check if it's open or not. For example:

```
if(!$(".selector").dialog("isOpen")) {
    // the dialog .selector is closed, you can open another one
}
```

**Update:**

If you want to close any other open dialogs before opening one, you can route all dialog open operations through a function which remembers what to close before opening another.

In this example, calling `openDialog` will close any other open dialog before opening the one you specify, and calling `closeDialog` will close the currently active dialog.

```
function closeDialog() {
}

function openDialog(selector) {
    closeDialog();

    $(selector).dialog("open");
    closeDialog = function() { 
        $(selector).dialog("close");
    };
}
```

The example "pollutes" the `window` object with the `closeDialog` and `openDialog` functions, but you can refactor that appropriately if you want.

Comment: thanks for response, 
but if i have 10 dialogs, i will have to check if .selector1 and .selector2 and .selector3 and .selector4 .... are open then close them all and open the one i need...???

Comment: ok, let's take this practical:
i have this:
                `$( "#edit1" ).live( "click", function() {
                        $( "#edit_dialog1" ).dialog( "open" );
   return false;
  });
  $( "#edit2" ).live( "click", function() {
                        $( "#edit_dialog2" ).dialog( "open" );
   return false;
  });
  $( "#edit3" ).live( "click", function() {
                        $( "#edit_dialog3" ).dialog( "open" );
   return false;
  });`

now i have to set all these dialogs to be closed in the `closeDialog()` function.  and then call them in the `openDialog()` one ??

Comment: @Patrioticcow: No. You just call e.g. `openDialog("#edit_dialog1")` whenever you want to open a dialog. That's it. The previous dialog will close automatically.

Comment: alright, but how do i know what dialog is open, because `function closeDialog() {}` is empty? This `selector` is the class given to one of the dialogs.

Comment: @Patrioticcow: Just set a variable inside `openDialog` and read its value whenever you want to check which dialog is open. Remember to set the variable back to `false` or something inside `closeDialog`. But in the future, please write *all* you requirements in the question text.

Comment: @Jon , YOUR ANSWER IS GREAT, THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply

```
if(!$('.ui-dialog').is(":visible")) {
//some stuff in here
}
```

Seems to do the trick fairly easily ?

Just saying ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

if(!$("#dialog-Save").data("dialog")._isOpen) {

..

}